# I want to copy job names in datastage designer

Tags: datastage

I want to copy job names in datastage designer
It doesn't work using 'Ctrl+C' and 'Ctrl+V'. How can I copy job names? also In pallete too.

[image: DATASTAGE DESIGNER]

Find in DATASTAGE Tutorial

Comment: Clarify your question please - what is the goal? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Listing jobs by Name and Category

You can list jobs (as they appear in design time) using the [`dssearch` command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/8.1?topic=jobs-search-by-name) at the command line interface:

`dssearch -ljobs -matches -sub [category] [-oc] [-oj] <project> [job]`

- sub The category is the "folder" you want to search in. Omit to search the entire project.
- oc enables to print out the category
- oj enables to print out the job type

Examples:

- `dssearch -ljobs -matches -sub pr01` lists all jobs of project pr01.
- `dssearch -ljobs -matches -sub "cat1/subcat2" pr01 CopyOf*` lists all jobs of project pr01 in the path "cat1/subcat2" beginning with "CopyOf*".

> The `dssearch` command lists all jobs in the project as they appear in design time. If you need to find jobs by runtime status, use the [`dsjob -ljobs` command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/9.1?topic=jobs-listing-projects-stages-links-parameters-queues).
> Note that the documentation for dssearch disappeared since version 8.5, but from my experience it still exists and works (as of version 11.7).